# How to install ROS on Poineer-3DX

Tags: ros, installation, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,everyone.
I have a Poineer-3DX robot, the onboard computer system now is Windows 2000. I can connect the robot with my laptop(already installed with ROS hydro and Ubuntu 12.04)  through a serial line。
My first question is: whether I should install ROS on the onboard computer? If I have to, how to install? The instruction of the [installation](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/AMR_Pioneer_Compatible) is not clear.

My second question is :When I send the command

`rostopic pub -1 /RosAria/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '{linear:  {x: 0.1, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}'`

to the real robot, it can move, but very slowly even I change the linear x velocity to a bigger value, what's the problem? However, if I run the command to the simulator, the change of the velocity works.

Thank you guys.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95411/how-to-install-ros-on-poineer-3dx/) by [hangzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/7501/hangzhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-10-30**:
This is just a guess (from working with p2os), but the robot may move slowly because somewhere in the params the max velocity value is set to a very small number. Sometimes, with ROS nodes, parameters are not documented well. See if you can find it in the source or if there is one set by the sim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On our pioneer-3d we have installed ros on the onboard computer. But if you can control it over laptop and the serial interface it will work that way two, in my opinion. But i personally prefer the onboard computer.
I have never used windows, but the Ubuntu/debian installation of rosaria is very well [http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA]. But the installation is still a little tricky, because ROSARIA does not follow all the conventions.
I am not sure but i think the application was build in a wrong folder and i had to copy it manually into my ros workspace.

To your second question, maybe there are buttons on the pioneer to control how fast he drives. I know that there is a button to stop the motors, maybe there are also some to configure the speed.

---

Originally posted by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) with karma: 336 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hangzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/7501/hangzhang/) on 2013-10-30**:
Thanks for your reply. For the first question, if you install ROS on the onboard computer, how would you use ROS with the Pioneer? I mean that maybe you need a  displayer to connect to robot and a keyboard  and a mouse。

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-11-05**:
you need a Monitor and a keyboard (maybee a mouse) to see the desktop. But you will just need it the first several times.
Simply use SSH, and debug via your workstation. Works fine.